# React js css inline style margin right not working

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to implement margin-right inline CSS to the below react span element:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";   
class NavBar extends Component {
  state = {
    totalCounters: 0,
  };      
  render() {    
    let styles = {
        margin-right: '20px',
        width: '250px',
        height: '250px',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      };
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Navbar
        </a>
        <span style={styles} className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">
          {this.props.totalCounters}
        </span>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}
export default NavBar;
```

But it shows syntax error, while no error if replacing `margin-right` with `margin`. So how to do it?

Comment: you can also use it like margin: "0 20px 0 0",

Answer (score 21, accepted):

React uses camelCase for inline style properties.  Try `marginRight: '20px'`, just like you did with `backgroundColor`.

Answer (score 4):

try this:
way a)

```
let styles = {
        marginRight: '20px',
        width: '250px',
        height: '250px',
        backgroundColor: 'yellow',
      };


 <span style={styles} className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">
```

way b)

```
<span style={{margin-right:"20px", width: '250px',height: '250px',background: 'yellow'}} className="badge badge-pill badge-secondary">
```